# Regex expression testing

Tags: regex

Hello I am trying to use regex to make sure the user has entered at minimum three dot points I think i am close but at the moment my expression will return unexpected results.

Here is my expression as of 30/01/17

```
/(•([\s]*[\w]+|[\.\,]*)*|\n){3,}/g
```

and here is the text snippet i am testing;

```
blahblahblahblahblahblahblah
blahblahblahblahblahblah
blahblahblahblahblahblah.

•   blahblahblahblahblahblah.
•blahblahblahblahblahblah.
blahblahblahblahblahblah.
.•blahblah,   blahblahblahblah.
```

NOTE: I put the full stop in place in the third dot point as it is the easiest way to trigger the unexpected result. 
Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look for non dots `[^.]` then a dot `[.]` followed by non dots `[^.]` three times:

```
/(?:[^.]*[.][^.]){3,}/
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/Qz8WaY/1)

You can use the same procedure of a `•` if that is the character you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Use a look ahead:

```
^(?=(.*\.){3}).*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex [`^ *•.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/sApGut/5), and if it finds three matches, then you have three lines starting will a bullet point. You have to use the multiline (m) flag, so `^` and `$` also match start and end of a line respectively. I can show you code if you tell me what language your are using.

If you only want to make sure the text contains three bullet points (ex: this `•••` can work), then don't use regex at all, your language most likely have a function to count matches of a character in a string.

Don't forget to upvote! ;)

Comment: Thank you for your response but i was hoping to have all three dot point returned in only one match, also my problem isn't so much weather or not the dot points exist but that they have some form of text neighbouring them. @Nicolas Maltais